# field separator causing in shell

Tags: sed

I am having csv file like:

```
 Apartments, 891 , 413 ," 1,623 "," 2,415 "," 6,565 "," 2,916 ", -   , 436 , -   , 620 ," 1,651 "," 2,050 "," 1,200 "," 3,073 ", 89 , -   , 24 ," 3,189 ", -   ," 3,2    18 "," 1,768 ", 580 , -   ," 1,107 "," 9,298 "," 9,178 "," 7,326 "," 3,356 "," 4,181 "," 2,912 "," 8,669 "," 2,584 "," 3,835 ", 901 ," 6,703 "," 7,150 "," 3,938 ","     13,867 "," 2,233 "," 6,839 "," 4,754 "," 6,594 ", -   ," 2,582 "," 2,359 ", 624 , 416 , -   ," 1,362 ", 280 ," 1,548 ", 595 ," 1,744 ", -   , 481 ," 1,285 "," 3,07    7 "," 3,734 "," 2,339 "," 2,220 "," 1,053 ", 632 ," 8,898 ", 539 , -   ," 4,355 "
```

I want all fileds to be seperated by | and all the numbers should be plain.
and no , in a number.

I want output like:

```
Apartments| 891 | 413 | 1623 | 2415 |6565 | 2916 | -  | 436 | -  | 620 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) and [tr](/questions/tagged/tr) commands you can easily achieve it, as follows;

```
sed -e 's/\(\"[^",]\+\),\([^",]*\)/\1\2/g' -e 's/\"//g' sample |tr ',' '|'
```

**Explanation:**

Firstly `sed` remove commas in between two quotations and then `tr` command replace all rest commas with pipe.

**Output:**

```
$ sed -e 's/\(\"[^",]\+\),\([^",]*\)/\1\2/g' -e 's/\"//g' sample.csv |tr ',' '|'
```

---

```
Apartments| 891 | 413 | 1623 | 2415 | 6565 | 2916 | -   | 436 | -   | 620 | 1651 | 2050 | 1200 | 3073 | 89 | -   | 24 
    | 3189 | -   | 32    18 | 1768 | 580 | -   | 1107 | 9298 | 9178 | 7326 | 3356 | 4181 | 2912 | 8669 | 2584 | 3835 | 901
     | 6703 | 7150 | 3938 |     13867 | 2233 | 6839 | 4754 | 6594 | -   | 2582 | 2359 | 624 | 416 | -   | 1362 | 280 | 154
    8 | 595 | 1744 | -   | 481 | 1285 | 307    7 | 3734 | 2339 | 2220 | 1053 | 632 | 8898 | 539 | -   | 4355
```